# Yii db connection behaviour

Tags: yii

Does yii keeps persistent connection for database ?

I find , even when browser window is closed, a long running mysql SELECT query keeps running in background and slowing others down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure db query timeout. 
For mysql you can control deadlock detection's timeout with 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' on the server, docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-innodb_lock_wait_timeout.html

Comment: There is no deadlock , however . only it is taking a lot of time. Can this work for SELECT queries. But i think SELECT query will not need a LOCK ?

Comment: @fortm Sure, you can set default_socket_timeout (via php.ini or ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 30)), http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/apis-php-mysqlnd.config.html#apis-php-ini.mysqlnd.net-read-timeout